# ejs and angular.js blank webpage

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to link an ejs to angular. However, I'm getting a blank page.

In my app.js file, I have:

```
app.get('/namespiechart', function(req, res) {
var datalist = [];
for (var i=0, t=6; i<t; i++) {
    datalist.push(Math.round(Math.random() * t))
}

//res.render('NamesPieChart',{ChartLabels :JSON.stringify(["January","February","March","April","May","June"]), DataList : JSON.stringify(datalist)});  

    res.json({ChartLabels : JSON.stringify(["January","February","March","April","May","June"]), DataList :     JSON.stringify(datalist)});
});
```

when I run the res.json I get this for a website:
{
  "ChartLabels": "[\"January\",\"February\",\"March\",\"April\",\"May\",\"June\"]",
  "DataList": "[0,2,2,1,1,4]"
}

However, when I run the render, the page shows up correctly. I just can't get the angular to link to the data from the database.

Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data passed, I ended up adding this on the ejs page:  ng-init= "m_datalist=<%-DataList%>"

I could then run the data and have it as a variable.